# BT disconnects when connection is no used

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Phone connects to the device correctly. The connection is not lost when app frequently sends information. But if there is no data transfer, then the connection is dropped within few seconds.

```
java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:428)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
at com.pnn.obdcardoctor_full.command.Base.readResult(Base.java:179)
at com.pnn.obdcardoctor_full.command.Base.run(Base.java:147)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

phone Nexus 4 (on older works fine)

Android 4.3

reconnect and ping isn't a solution.

**UPDATE**

works fine on the test devices (including Nexus 4 with Android 4.3).

Users send me the logs. Judging by them disconnect through a certain period of time(common in the logs is an android version above 4.0).

Possible third-party applications that interfere with or nuances to work with bluetooth 4.0